# Laravel : Increase time on second time login attempts

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Currently five login attempts blocks user for 1 minute and its working fine with the following code :

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

**What i want is that, When a user gets unblocked again after the first attempts, On the second attempts the block time should increase to 3 minutes.**

I searched around, But could not found anything, Is there any way around it ?

Comment: You'll need to probably have a db table where you store ip, login attempts, timeout, timeout_time etc. If ip has 5 login attempts then set timeout to 60 seconds, timeout_time to now+timeout, login attempts to 0. Something like that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest you try the following code. Please ask if anything is unclear.

```
$minutes = 3;
$key = $this->throttleKey($request);
$rateLimiter = $this->limiter();

if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {

    $attempts = $rateLimiter->attempts($key); 
    if ($attempts > 1) {
        $attempts === 2 && $rateLimiter->clear($key);
        $this->decayMinutes = ($attempts - 1) * $minutes;
        $attempts === 2 && $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

Code for incremental blocking:

```
$minutes = 3;
$key = $this->throttleKey($request);
$rateLimiter = $this->limiter();

if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {

    $attempts = $rateLimiter->attempts($key);
    $rateLimiter->clear($key);
    $this->decayMinutes = $attempts === 1 ? 1 : ($attempts - 1) * $minutes;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $attempts; $i++) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

Code for incremental blocking with cache:

```
$minutes = 3;
$key = $this->throttleKey($request);
$rateLimiter = $this->limiter();

if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {

    $attempts = $rateLimiter->attempts($key);
    $rateLimiter->clear($key); // might have to add logic here

    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($rateLimiter);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('cache');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $cache = $property->getValue($rateLimiter);
    $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionMethod($rateLimiter, 'availableAt');
    $reflectionMethod->setAccessible(true);

    $blockMinutes = $attempts === 1 ? 1 : $attempts > 1 ? ($attempts - 1) * $minutes : 1;
    $cache->add($key.':timer', $reflectionMethod->invoke($rateLimiter, $blockMinutes * 60), $blockMinutes);
    $added = $cache->add($key, 0, $blockMinutes);
    $hits = (int) $cache->increment($key, $attempts);
    if (! $added && $hits === 1) {
        $cache->put($key, 1, $blockMinutes);
    }

    $reflectionMethod->setAccessible(false);
    $property->setAccessible(false);

    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: Good work there, Need your quick minute, What will be the best way to scale it to 3 throttles to increase block time on each throttle ?

Comment: I am adding the conditions on `$attempt > 2`, Like `$attempt >= 3`, But its not working, And what do you mean by `However, the way Laravel works you need to call the lines with $attemts === 2 on each call and afterwards call incrementLoginAttemts the amount of times as the $attempts value.`, Can you show it to me by editing the answer please ?

Comment: Your approach makes good sense, But it gives an error `availableAt is a protected method`, Please look into it to make your answer more credible to others. Thanks

Comment: Please also give a look to seconds,  It comes in large negative number.

Comment: Ok, I changed the code (final edit). If there are any new issues, start a new thread/question. I actually installed php and Laravel 5.5 just to test that it worked. I **free-coded** before because I rarely use php nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to set property in LoginController:

```
public $decayMinutes = 1; // minutes to lockout
```

Also you can controll numbers of attempts:

```
public $maxAttempts = 5;
```

For more information you can investigate:
trait AuthenticatesUsers - which has method "login" and code from your description. 
And this trait uses another trait: 
"ThrottlesLogins" -> this traits has method named "decayMinutes". It returns number of minutes.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: But how will i know that this user is blocked once, And he is attempting logins for the second time ?

Comment: My question is that, I want to increase the time of blockage if the user is heading towards second blockage.

Comment: @Gammer It's not easy. Because after user gets unblocked, RateLimiter clears the hits and lockout timer for the given key (for user). And it removes any information fro cache. Probably you will need to store some information yourself. Just seems Laravel doesn't provide functionality what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think laravel default doesn't provide what your need, So you need to save in (cache, session or database) if user had blocked once on your own, and increase `decayMinutes` as you want.

```
if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    if(Cache::has($this->throttleKey($request))){
        $this->decayMinutes = 3;
    }

    Cache::put($this->throttleKey($request), true);
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: You could even go a step further and store the last used `$decayMinutes` in the cache. You could then always increase it by another 3 minutes, i.e. `1 -> 4 -> 7 -> 10 -> ...`. It would probably be a good idea to clear this cache item on a successful login, though.

Comment: It still locks me for 1 minute, Not for 3.