# Increase time on multiple failed login attempts in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

Currently, five login attempts to block a user for one minute by default. I want to design the system like:

1. After the first three failed login attempts, block the user for 2 minutes.
2. After that, for the next two failed login attempt (that is total 5th time), block user for 5 minutes.

**ThrottlesLogins.php**

```php
public function maxAttempts()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'maxAttempts') ? $this->maxAttempts : 2;
}

public function decayMinutes()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'decayMinutes') ? $this->decayMinutes : 2;
}
```

**LoginController.php**

```php
public function adminLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);

    $key = $this->throttleKey($request);
    $rateLimiter = $this->limiter();

    // Check if the user has too many login attempts.
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $attempts = $rateLimiter->attempts($key);
        $rateLimiter->clear($key);
        if ($attempts === 5) {
            $this->decayMinutes = 5;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $attempts; $i++) {
            $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        }

        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);  // Fire the lockout event.

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request); //Redirect the user back after lockout.
    }

    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 
        'password' => $request->password], $request->get('remember'))) {

        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }

    // Keep track of login attempts from the user.
    $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

I have already followed this: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854395/laravel-increase-time-on-second-time-login-attempts)

But it does not solve my problem. How can I achieve such a system?